# In a naive attempt to calculate the derivative of $x^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x)=x^x$ with $x>0$. One has the following derivatives
$$
(x^n)'=nx^{n-1},\quad (a^x)'=a^x\ln a\;.
$$
Neither of these applies to the function $f$. In other words, it is **neither**
$
f'(x)=xx^{x-1}
$
**nor**
$
f'(x)=x^x\ln x.
$

But if we naively just *add* them together, we get
$$
f'(x)=xx^{x-1}+x^x\ln x\tag{1}
$$

By definition, $f(x)=\exp(x\ln x)$ and thus by the chain rule:
$$
f'(x) = f(x)\cdot (x\ln x)' = x^x (\ln x+x\cdot \frac{1}{x})=x^x(\ln x+1)\tag{2}
$$

One can see that (1) and (2) are the SAME. Is this a coincidence? Is there any underlying math to reveal the coincidence?

Comment: See [this Littlewood-style joke](https://mathoverflow.net/a/38901) from MO.

Comment: I think you mean "naive", not "native".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Ah, corrected. Thanks. The spelling was really naive if you forgive the pun :-).

Answer (score 11):

I just find that I can never come up with an explanation restricting myself in 1D. However, if I have *one more* dimension, I have the following explanation.

If we let $g(u,v)=u^v$, then $f(x) = g(x,x)$. By the chain rule in multivariable calculus, we get
$$
f'(x) = g_u\cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+g_v\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
where $u(x) = v(x)= x$ and $g_u = vu^{v-1}$ and $g_v=u^v\ln u$. Combining everything together one justifies the "naive" attemp (1).

This is one answer I can come up with explaining the coincidence. It seems that there is no hope to work it out without using multivariable calculus. (I would be glad to be proved wrong and see other answers.)

Comment: Yeah, this is the heart of it, and applies to any $h(x,x,x,\dots,x).$ Ig $g(u,v)=uv,$ then you get the product rule from the above answer, getting the derivative of $f_1(x)f_2(x)=g(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ using that $g_u(u,v)=v, g_v(u,v)=u.$